# if we change the norm, is it possible to make it complete ?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functional-analysis

There are many examples about $C^1[0,1]$ that is not complete under supremum norm. if we change the norm, is it possible to make it complete ? Are there any examples about this ? 
Thank you for your help .

Comment: There is a procedure called completion that turns a metric space into a complete metric space. It involves an abstract space with equivalence classes of Cauchy sequences. In this specific case, I think you will end up with $C[0,1]$.

Comment: If you allow arbitrary choice of norm, then you are only retaining the vector space structure of $C^1[0,1]$.  As a vector space, this is isomorphic to any other vector space of equicardinal dimension, so just pick any complete normed space of that size and impose its norm onto $C^1[0,1]$ via the linear transformation.

Comment: Yes examples about $C^1[0,1]$, not about subspaces of $C^1[0,1]$. Without completion can we make it complete by changing the norm ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, define a "stronger" norm (the $C^1$-norm!) $|f|_{C^1}$ to be the sum of the sup-norm of $f$ and the sup-norm of $f'$. The proof of completeness of $C^1[a,b]$ with this norm does require something, since we need to show that the derivative of a limit (in this norm) is the (sup-norm) limit of the derivative. (For example, the fundamental theorem of calculus nearly proves this.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of considering :

$$||f||:=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)| $$

Choose :

$$||f||_1:=\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)|+\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f'(x)| $$

Using this I think that if you take $(f_n)$ to be a Cauchy sequence for this norm you must have that both $(f_n)$ and $(f_n')$ are Cauchy sequence for the usual supremum norm so $f_n\rightarrow_n f$ and $f_n'\rightarrow g$ then you just have to show that $f'=g$.